# Why is it "loggable" rather than "logable"?

Tags: orthography

I am using '***loggable***' in the name of an interface written in a .NET programming language. It is among the many words that make sense in a programming context but aren't (yet) listed in English Dictionaries, as are *serializable*, *deserialization*, and *multiton*. *Loggable* seems like the correct spelling to me, but I can't pinpoint the reason. Similar words such as *floggable* and *taggable* have double 'g', but Google search also returns usage of their single 'g' counterparts, albeit the single 'g' seems to be less widespread.

Does anyone know a reason my brain likes "loggable" as opposed to "logable" for the correct spelling? A concrete rule would be great.

Comment: Yes, that is the spelling. And it is a word, meaning 'capable of being logged legally'. As for the reasons, it's a long story.

Comment: Why "loggable", not "logable"? I can't find it in a dictionary. Is it legal jargon, just as it is programming jargon?

Comment: @DanVerdolino Because that is how it works. See *droppable, dottable, gettable, hittable, settable, stoppable* vs *impotable, notable, votable*.

Comment: @tchrist so the general rule is double the consonant unless the word ends in a silent e? I see exceptions in peaceable and abolishable among others, but I accept it.

Comment: Single consonant, short vowel: it can't be alone; it needs its pal!

Comment: No, the rule is: if the vowel was short in Middle English (/ɪ ɛ æ ɔ ə/) and it uses only one vowel letter and it's in a syllable ended by a consonant, **then** you double the consonant in spelling. If you don't, you get a vowel that was long in Middle English, and is now tense, respectively, /ay i e o u/. If you know Middle English, this is not a problem. If you don't, however, it is.

Comment: http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/loggable

Comment: The other question (if it were a not-yet-existent word) would be -able or -ible.

Comment: If it can be *legible*, it could be *logible* (with a softened *g*)? (Incidentally, the latter means 'transportable' from *logistics*.)

Comment: @JohnLawler most people can't reference knowledge of Middle English to determine a correct spelling.

Comment: @simchona Google 'logable' and you will see that spelling being widely used. It is not as cut and dry as you thought. Thank you, however, for turning me off from ELU.

Comment: @Kris I'll use 'loggable' because it looks better, but 'legible' piqued my interest. However, I can't find the English infinitive of legible.

Comment: Googling "logable" also yields the correction "did you mean loggable"

Comment: @DanVerdolino: That's because it's a Latin infinitive: _[lego, legere, legi, lectus](http://sphinx.metameat.net/latin.php?paradigm=lego)_ 'read'. _Legibilis_ is a Latin adjective, which was borrowed along with dozens of other Latin words from the same root. Look up any verb in a Latin dictionary (they're cheap at used bookstores) and you'll find a half-dozen words from the same root that we use in English, already minted by the Romans and imported into English in one of the waves of Latin and French that poured into England.

Comment: @simchona Google suggest is not an authority. It tells us 'loggable' is more widely used. It is my preferred spelling. I was just asking for a rule since the search also displays many examples of 'logable'

Comment: @JohnLawler of course Latin sees its roots in many English words.  I thought it was interesting that the infinitive of 'legible' didn't make it into English, which might have given us a look into a reasoning behind 'logable' over 'loggable'... Anyway, I like 'loggable' and if you want to compile your very helpful Middle English and Latin explanations, I will mark as answer. Thanks

Comment: **Logable* is wrong because it violates the existing pattern that applies to all other such words. It must be, and is, *loggable*.

Comment: @tchrist all I was asking was for a concrete rule. There are **many** words in the English language which have spelling that violate existing patterns and are not wrong.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, [loggable](http://www.wordnik.com/words/loggable) appears to be in use and preferred over *logable*. You appear to prefer it to because you are accustomed to the pattern with other words such as the ones listed in your post.

Most people here will tell you that there are no *concrete* rules in English. But as a [rule of thumb](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_and_British_English_spelling_differences#Doubled_consonants), for words ending with a single consonant, if the suffix begins with a vowel, then the afore-noted consonant is doubled. Therefore, *log* becomes *loggable*.

There are, I'm sure, many exceptions to this rule, some of which can be explained with caveats involving stress and other whatnots.

---

Here is John Lawler's explanation [from the comments](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/106938/why-is-it-loggable-rather-than-logable#comment218075_106938):

> No, the rule is: if the vowel was short in Middle English (/ɪ ɛ æ ɔ ə/) and it uses only one vowel letter and it's in a syllable ended by a consonant, **then** you double the consonant in spelling. If you don't, you get a vowel that was long in Middle English, and is now tense, respectively, /ay i e o u/. If you know Middle English, this is not a problem. If you don't, however, it is.

> That's because it's a Latin infinitive: [lego, legere, legi, lectus](http://sphinx.metameat.net/latin.php?paradigm=lego) 'read'. *Legibilis* is a Latin adjective, which was borrowed along with dozens of other Latin words from the same root. Look up any verb in a Latin dictionary (they're cheap at used bookstores) and you'll find a half-dozen words from the same root that we use in English, already minted by the Romans and imported into English in one of the waves of Latin and French that poured into England.