# Which is right "reblogable" or "rebloggable"?

Tags: meaning, word-choice

Which word is right for something that is worthy of reblogging?

On urbandictionary.com there seem to be similar definition for both words.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is is a neologism, there is not much on it. Wiktionary has a few instances:

***[Rebloggable](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/rebloggable)***

> - Capable of, or suitable for, being reblogged.
>
>   - 2009, Curt Cloninger, Fresher Styles for Web Designers: More Eye Candy from the Underground, New Riders (2009), ISBN 9780321562692, page 117:
>       Every blog post is potentially rebloggable via RSS technology.

- ***Loggable*** has a bit longer story as shown in ***[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=loggable&year_start=1980&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cloggable%3B%2Cc0).*** As suggested ***[here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/106938/why-is-it-loggable-rather-than-logable)*** usage appears to prefer the double consonant.

> - "Most people here will tell you that there are no concrete rules in English. But as a rule of thumb, for words ending with a single consonant, if the suffix begins with a vowel, then the afore-noted consonant is doubled. Therefore, log becomes loggable."

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to give such a detailed answer.